# sql recursive cte in view not work fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, view, common-table-expression

I made a CTE query that will works fine in a stored procedure and when i execute in query-editor (With where statement)

But when i try it out to create the same as View (Without where statement).
And execute this with the where statement i get the data not recursive.
I dont see the mistake.

This is the Query in SP and query-editor which works fine. (Guid in SP is as parameter)

```
WITH recursiveTable(ParentApplicationRoleId, ChildApplicationRoleId)
AS
(
    SELECT ParentApplicationRoleId, ChildApplicationRoleId
        FROM ApplicationRoleParentChild
        WHERE ParentApplicationRoleId = '69BCC94B-2884-4270-B39E-A09669C1D658'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ApplicationRoleParentChild.ParentApplicationRoleId, ApplicationRoleParentChild.ChildApplicationRoleId
        FROM ApplicationRoleParentChild
        INNER JOIN recursiveTable ON ApplicationRoleParentChild.ParentApplicationRoleId = recursiveTable.ChildApplicationRoleId   
)
/* Get all Childelements (from recursive Table) and add the ParentRoleId to this List */
SELECT ApplicationRole.Name AS RoleName
    FROM recursiveTable
    INNER JOIN ApplicationRole ON ApplicationRole.ApplicationRoleId = recursiveTable.ChildApplicationRoleId 
    UNION
    SELECT Name AS RoleName FROM ApplicationRole WHERE ApplicationRoleId = '69BCC94B-2884-4270-B39E-A09669C1D658'
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

As Result i get [Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ttsqk.png)

The View need all ApplicationRoles (with all Childroles) and unfiltered, because i'll use the filter when i call the View.

How i can change the CTE that it works without where statement?

I have this as example. But it returns only the direct Childelements of 'Administrator'
And i search Child from the Childs, too.

```
WITH recursiveTable(ParentApplicationRoleId, ChildApplicationRoleId)
AS
(
    SELECT ParentApplicationRoleId, ChildApplicationRoleId
        FROM ApplicationRoleParentChild
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ApplicationRoleParentChild.ParentApplicationRoleId, ApplicationRoleParentChild.ChildApplicationRoleId
        FROM ApplicationRoleParentChild
        INNER JOIN recursiveTable ON ApplicationRoleParentChild.ParentApplicationRoleId = recursiveTable.ChildApplicationRoleId   
)
/* Get all Childelements (from recursive Table) and add the ParentRoleId to this List */
    SELECT ApplicationRole.Name AS ChildRoleName, Parent.Name AS ParentRoleName
    FROM recursiveTable
    INNER JOIN ApplicationRole ON ApplicationRole.ApplicationRoleId = recursiveTable.ChildApplicationRoleId 
    INNER JOIN ApplicationRole as Parent ON Parent.ApplicationRoleId = recursiveTable.ParentApplicationRoleId 

/*The Query-Filter when i call the View: Like SELECT * FROM View WHERE Parent.Name = 'Administrator'
    Expected Returns: Role1-10, Departement1-3 and Administrator
    Current Returns: Only direct Childs (Role2,7,8, Departement1,3)

    Departement2 is Child of Departement1
    And some other Roles are in one of the Departements or roles
*/
```

Tables:
ApplicationRole (all Roles)
ApplicationRoleParentChild (All Parent Child Relationships) (With FK Parent and FK Child Role)

I Hope someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: `WHERE ParentApplicationRoleId is NULL` ? First select - top level, second select - tree expanded.

Comment: yes, it is correct using of cte - to define where clause for top level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yor `where` clause filters all records. and deeper records have no direct parent Administrator.
To filter by it you can store top level record name as a column in cte

```
WITH recursiveTable(ParentApplicationRoleId, ChildApplicationRoleId, TopLevelName)
AS
(
    SELECT ParentApplicationRoleId, ChildApplicationRoleId, Name
        FROM ApplicationRoleParentChild
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ApplicationRoleParentChild.ParentApplicationRoleId, ApplicationRoleParentChild.ChildApplicationRoleId
        , recursiveTable.TopLevelName
        FROM ApplicationRoleParentChild
        INNER JOIN recursiveTable ON ApplicationRoleParentChild.ParentApplicationRoleId = recursiveTable.ChildApplicationRoleId   
)
```

or you can even build full path to child

```
   WITH recursiveTable(ParentApplicationRoleId, ChildApplicationRoleId, TopLevelName)
    AS
    (
        SELECT ParentApplicationRoleId, ChildApplicationRoleId, cast(Name as varchar(1000))
            FROM ApplicationRoleParentChild

        UNION ALL
        SELECT ApplicationRoleParentChild.ParentApplicationRoleId, ApplicationRoleParentChild.ChildApplicationRoleId
            , left(recursiveTable.TopLevelName + '/' + name, 1000)
            FROM ApplicationRoleParentChild
            INNER JOIN recursiveTable ON ApplicationRoleParentChild.ParentApplicationRoleId = recursiveTable.ChildApplicationRoleId   
    )
```

and then filter like `where Parent.TopLevelName like '%Administrator%'`

**update**
as notised 
*Ivan Starostin* in his comment
if you don't wat to get all combitations of hierarchy with every record as top level. 
You have to add `where` clause for the first select in cte to define topLevel nodes. 
something like `ParentApplicationRoleId is NULL` or `ParentApplicationRoleId = ''`